# How to create a SQL nested queries to get a JSON nested format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, pandas, nested

I have a sample data table in SQL below

| Sales_Order | PO_number | Booking_number | Container_number | Seal_number | ETD1 | ETA1 | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17493993 | 4338_A | MXO0583354 | CAIU9661214 | H4131037 | 30/06/2022 | 04/08/2022 | Jordan |
| 17493996 | 4338_A | MXO0583354 | CMAU4496275 | H4131039 | 30/06/2022 | 04/08/2022 | Jordan |
| 17699594 | 4355 | 190VC0059204 | MSMU8090753 | FJ14673712 | 02/07/2022 | 11/08/2022 | Jordan |
| 17699593 | 4355 | 190VC0059204 | MSDU7050180 | FJ14673630 | 02/07/2022 | 11/08/2022 | Jordan |
| 17699591 | 4355 | 190VC0059204 | CAIU7594190 | FJ14673612 | 02/07/2022 | 11/08/2022 | Jordan |
| 18193374 | Order_for_September_2 | 190VC0059041 | MSMU8133238 | FJ14673638 | 06/07/2022 | 19/08/2022 | Latvia |

I want to get the output in the required nested Json format as below

```
[{
    "Sales_Order": 17493993,
    "PO_number": "4338_A",
    "Booking_number": "MXO0583354",
    "Container_number": "CAIU9661214",
    "Seal_number": "H4131037",
    "ETD1": "30/06/2022",
    "ETA1": "04/08/2022",
    "Country": "Jordan",
    "Sub_Rows": [{
        "Sales_Order": 17493996,
        "PO_number": "4338_A",
        "Booking_number": "MXO0583354",
        "Container_number": "CMAU4496275",
        "Seal_number": "H4131039",
        "ETD1": "30/06/2022",
        "ETA1": "04/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan",
                }]
    },{
    "Sales_Order": 17699594,
    "PO_number": "4335",
    "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
    "Container_number": "MSMU8090753",
    "Seal_number": "FJ14673712",
    "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
    "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
    "Country": "Jordan",
    "Sub_Rows": [{
        "Sales_Order": 17699593,
        "PO_number": "4335",
        "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
        "Container_number": "MSDU7050180",
        "Seal_number": "FJ14673630",
        "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
        "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan",
                }],
    "Sub_Rows": [{
        "Sales_Order": 17699591,
        "PO_number": "4335",
        "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
        "Container_number": "CAIU7594190",
        "Seal_number": "FJ14673612",
        "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
        "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan",
                }],
    },{
    "Sales_Order": 18193374,
    "PO_number": "Order_for_September_2",
    "Booking_number": "190VC0059041",
    "Container_number": "MSMU8133238",
    "Seal_number": "FJ14673638",
    "ETD1": "06/07/2022",
    "ETA1": "19/08/2022",
    "Country": "Latvia",
    }
]
```

Here, I need to apply a condition : if the booking number has more than 1 container number, 1st booking number will be on the root and the following booking numbers will be on the sub_rows of the root.

I am trying to groupby in SQL however not successful to achieve the required output?
Any help will be appreciated?

My queryso far

```
SELECT 
   *, 
   Sub_Rows = ( Select * FROM [DMS_Backend].[dbo].[DMS_DEV] as V where V.Booking_number = H.Booking_number for JSON Path ) 
FROM [DMS_Backend].[dbo].[DMS_DEV] as H 
group By H.Sales_Order, H.PO_number, H.Booking_number, H.Container_number, H.Seal_number, H.ETA1, H.ETD1, H.Country for JSON Path
```

Comment: which database are you using and most of them have json_object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a `ROW_NUMBER()` for running counts of booking number. Then, including in outer query values equal to 1 and subquery values after 1:

```sql
WITH H AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY Booking_number
               ORDER BY Container_number
           ) AS rn
    FROM [DMS_Backend].[dbo].[DMS_DEV]
)

SELECT 
   Sales_Order, PO_number, Booking_number, Container_number, 
   Seal_number, ETD1, ETA1, Country,
   Sub_Rows = ( 
      SELECT Sales_Order, PO_number, Booking_number, Container_number, 
             Seal_number, ETD1, ETA1, Country 
      FROM H AS V 
      WHERE V.Booking_number = H_PLUS.Booking_number 
        AND V.rn > 1
      FOR JSON PATH
   ) 
FROM H
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY Sales_Order, PO_number, Booking_number, Container_number, 
         Seal_number, ETD1, ETA1, Country
ORDER BY Sales_Order, PO_number, Booking_number, Container_number, 
         Seal_number, ETD1, ETA1, Country
FOR JSON PATH
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "Sales_Order": 17493993,
    "PO_number": "4338_A",
    "Booking_number": "MXO0583354",
    "Container_number": "CAIU9661214",
    "Seal_number": "H4131037",
    "ETD1": "30/06/2022",
    "ETA1": "04/08/2022",
    "Country": "Jordan",
    "Sub_Rows": [
      {
        "Sales_Order": 17493996,
        "PO_number": "4338_A",
        "Booking_number": "MXO0583354",
        "Container_number": "CMAU4496275",
        "Seal_number": "H4131039",
        "ETD1": "30/06/2022",
        "ETA1": "04/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sales_Order": 17699591,
    "PO_number": "4355",
    "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
    "Container_number": "CAIU7594190",
    "Seal_number": "FJ14673612",
    "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
    "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
    "Country": "Jordan",
    "Sub_Rows": [
      {
        "Sales_Order": 17699593,
        "PO_number": "4355",
        "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
        "Container_number": "MSDU7050180",
        "Seal_number": "FJ14673630",
        "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
        "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan"
      },
      {
        "Sales_Order": 17699594,
        "PO_number": "4355",
        "Booking_number": "190VC0059204",
        "Container_number": "MSMU8090753",
        "Seal_number": "FJ14673712",
        "ETD1": "02/07/2022",
        "ETA1": "11/08/2022",
        "Country": "Jordan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sales_Order": 18193374,
    "PO_number": "Order_for_September_2",
    "Booking_number": "190VC0059041",
    "Container_number": "MSMU8133238",
    "Seal_number": "FJ14673638",
    "ETD1": "06/07/2022",
    "ETA1": "19/08/2022",
    "Country": "Latvia"
  }
]
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-kvwxoF6)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a perfect solution. was struggling, but you made my day so easier.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!